# Typed Promise changes return type to unknown when `finally` is added

Tags: typescript, es6-promise

I have a regular promise with a statically typed return type:

```
export const hasActiveSubscription = (whatEver: string): Promise<string> => 
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (true){
      return resolve('imastring')
    }
    return reject(new Error('nope'))
  })
```

So far so good, but if I add a finally block, it changes the return type to `unknown` and fails to deliver that string type, e.g.

```
export const hasActiveSubscription = (whatEver: string): Promise<string> => 
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (true){
      resolve('imastring')
    }
    reject(new Error('nope'))
  }).finally(console.info)
```

> Type 'Promise' is not assignable to type 'Promise'.
> Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'.

How can I retain the original return type while keeping the `finally` block?

If it helps, my actual code has a `setTimeout` (to be sure this function doesn't take too long to return) and I want to clear the timeout on finally, instead of clearing a timeout on 5 different locations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you remove type annotation from the return position of the function signature, you will notice that the actual return type is `Promise<unknown>`, not the `Promise<string>` as you expected, which constitutes the first part of the error:

```ts
const hasActiveSubscription: (whatEver: string) => Promise<unknown>;
```

`Promise` is a generic interface, and its `finally` method uses the type parameter of the interface in its return type annotation (the sample is from the ES2018 lib):

```ts
interface Promise<T> {
    finally(onfinally?: (() => void) | undefined | null): Promise<T>
}
```

All you need to do is to specify the type of the constructed Promise, and everything will be a-ok:

```ts
export const hasActiveSubscription = (whatEver: string) => 
  new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
    if (true){
      resolve('imastring')
    }
    reject(new Error('nope'))
  }).finally(console.info) //no error, Promise<string> is inferred
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=5&jsx=0&ssl=7&ssc=27&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wBYENUEEEwCWAbsAMoCuARqglIWESnALxwAUA7tjAKKlQAXHHT1kAcwCUrAHxwAsACg4cZME5wAClAgBbQqmAAeUYQkz27KMFQQANqQA0cawCtgBaSzkBvJSpVCADMOGCgKYEk-ZQCVa1sHYHYAckJdHDCzcWTJfwCAXzy44HcCdjUNXigdKBTkCDBgHNyY-MkAOiCzLDs7AE92JDR7YHazIIgWoA)

---

Small note - your example has an unmatched bracket in the `reject` call